# Directive and controller communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a filtering component for a search app and it's my first dip into AngularJS.

Here's a Plunker or what I've got so far, it works how I want it to:

http://plnkr.co/I6ewaU

There are two things which concern me with this implementation:

- I have to pass `filters` as an attribute of the `filter` directive to get access to `filters` on the `MainController`, surely there must be a better way to do this? I want to modify the `filters` object without having to pass it as an attribute.
- Is it correct to define `addFilter` in the `filtergroup` directive, or should this be defined on `MainController`?

I have been searching on Google for a while, but can't seem to find an alternative and would appreciate any help with this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS way is to show what it does in html.
Html has to explain the functionality by not hiding it to JS.

For example, how do I know this update filters unless I read your JS? Thus, try not to make any unless it is necessary. If you make any directive, try to expose the functionality to html.

```
<filtergroup type="filter-name" filter-store="filters">
```

And there are lots of good directives in Angularjs. I always use them first.

This is how I would do it, http://plnkr.co/edit/okCp5FZJo1ZR9962uaHT?p=preview

```
    <div class="sidebar">
        <p>Filters: {{ filters }}</p>
        filter1 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters[1]"/><br/>
        filter2 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters[2]"/><br/>
        filter3 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters[3]"/><br/>
        filter4 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters[4]"/><br/>
        filter5 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="filters[5]"/><br/>
    </div>
```

"less code, less manitenance"

Comment: Just to say, I took your advice and did everything using just built-in AngularJS directives. I tried to overcomplicate the solution too much, cheers!